# Ubuntu 18.04: easyABC install issues

Tags: 18.04, midi

I've been having troubles getting easyABC to work properly, on Ubuntu 18.04.04 (64 bit).

The install is here:

https://ifdo.ca/~seymour/easy/

http://abcplus.sourceforge.net/#EasyABC

I downloaded easyabc_1.3.7.7-1_all.deb, and ran that with Software Install.

In addition, some dependencies were required, these were installed in terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk-media3.0 
sudo apt-get install abcm2ps abcmidi
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python-pyparsing
```

When I run "easyabc" in terminal to open the program, I get this message in terminal:

```
Debug: ScreenToClient cannot work when toplevel window is not shown
```

And, once I try to play some music with EasyABC, several instances of the following error shows up in terminal:

```
(easy_abc.py:18107): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:03:32.596: Negative content width -9 (allocation 1, extents 5x5) while allocating gadget (node checkbutton, owner GtkCheckButton)
(easy_abc.py:18107): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:03:32.596: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkCheckButton
```

EasyABC interface opens properly, except, an error message:

```
Media playback error: Resource not found.
Media playback error: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
```

I can press "Ok", but unsurprisingly, when I copy some ABC code, it doesn't display the sheet music quite right (time signatures are displayed strangely), and, when I try to play the music from some ABC's, I get the EasyABC error message:

```
Media playback error: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Media playback error: Internal data stream error.
```

I do not have these issues on Windows 8 with EasyABC. I've looked at a few possible solutions online, with no luck thus far. I've also in general had troubles getting midi files to play on Ubuntu in the past, perhaps this is related.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there any extra information I need to post here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Xubuntu 20.04, there is a work around.

Edit:

> /usr/share/easyabc/easy_abc.py

Go to line 4456:

> self.mc.Load('NONEXISTANT_FILE____.mid')

Hash it out:

> #self.mc.Load('NONEXISTANT_FILE____.mid')

Save the file. This cured the problem for me.

I found it here:

> https://sourceforge.net/p/easyabc/discussion/general/thread/524f3f9c/?limit=25